# what is meant by field generated by primes over rationals?

Tags: prime-numbers, extension-field

In the paper titled "Reducing Randomness via irrational numbers" by Chen & Kao ([found here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/9907011.pdf)), while proving lemma 2.1 they state :

> let $B_j$ be the field generated by $p_{1,1}, . . . , p_{1,k1}, . . . , p_{j,1}, . . . , p_{j,k_j}$ over $B_0$, where $B_0$ is a field of rational numbers and $p_{i,j}$'s are primes.

I donot understand how $B_j$ is an extension of $B_0$ since all the primes are already in $B_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a typo; from context it's clear that Chen and Kao intend to adjoin the square roots $\sqrt{p_{i,j}}$.